# How to write this in php curl

Tags: php, curl, picasa

I want to upload a picture to Google picasa using curl, I found this line of code which uploads the picture to Google picasa using curl But I don't know how to convert it to php and curl to be able to use it.

```
curl --silent --request POST --data-binary "@sweeping_the_rock.png" --header "Slug: Sweeping the rock" --header "Content-Type: image/png" --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=ABCDEFG" "http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/brad.gushue/albumid/5113621341847124417" | tidy -xml -indent -quiet

$file = "C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/182178_271150652992340_118089494_n.jpg";
$postimg = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userId/albumid/albumId";
$header = array("Content-Type: image/jpeg",
         "Content-Length: ".filesize($file),
         "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$token",
         "Slug: 182178_271150652992340_118089494_n.jpg"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postimg);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($file));
$hasil = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL#media-support

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. While you may be having trouble with your program, we highly encourage (and insist) that you give it your best shot before asking the community for help. When it's clear that you're running into issues with code that you've tried, we're glad to help! If you don't put any effort into designing your own solutions, we tend to down-vote your question and close it. You must at least attempt a solution first. Never ask someone else to write code in lieu of an honest effort. In short, [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: The [PHP Curl docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) should prove useful.

Comment: So where are you having problems? Are you getting curl Errors?  Are you not getting the response you expect from the the API?

Comment: Yes it responds with false and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not sending the file correctly. you need to add the CURL_OPTs for file upload so it's mime-encoded and transferred correctly  (POSTing a file upload is a totally different form-encoding then sending simple post data)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> CURLOPT_INFILE     The file that the transfer should be read from when uploading.
>
> CURLOPT_INFILESIZE     The expected size, in bytes, of the file when uploading a file to a remote site. Note that using this option will not stop libcurl from sending more data, as exactly what is sent depends on CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.